# Laravel 8 - Why can I not paginate this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, query-builder

I have a Laravel API call, and I want to paginate the result, but can't seem to find the way that works. My call looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $per_page = $request->input('per_page');

    if(!$per_page)
        $per_page=20;

    $creditos = Prestacion::all();
    $creditos = $creditos->paginate($per_page);
    return $this->collection($creditos, new PrestacionTransformer);
}
```

This returns the error:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you are running the query before paginating it.
Check this line:

```
$creditos = Prestacion::all();
```

The `all()` method executes the query. This means that `$creditos` is now an instance of `Collection` instead of `QueryBuilder`. This is the reason why. the `paginate()` method doesn't exist in the class.

You should do instead:

```
$creditos = Prestacion::paginate();

return $this->collection($creditos, new PrestacionTransformer);
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, but now I got the error "Argument 1 passed to Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Response\\Factory::collection() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Support\\Collection, instance of Illuminate\\Pagination\\LengthAwarePaginator given"

Comment: @IvánFloresVázquez, Try using `return $this->collection(collect(Prestacion::all()), new PrestacionTransformer);`

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Now it says "Unable to find bound transformer for \"App\\Models\\PrestamosCreditos\\Prestacion\" class". And, wouldn't that return the whole collection, and not it paginated?